# PySpark Dataframe Transformation from_json

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

i have below JSON which i am reading from Kafka and then tyring to convert to StructType using from_json function.

```
schema_session_start = StructType([
    StructField("ID", StringType()),
    StructField("SID", StringType()),
    StructField("EP", LongType()),
    StructField("IP", StringType()),
    StructField("LN", StringType()),
    StructField("VN", StringType()),
    StructField("DV", StructType([
        StructField("MK", StringType()),
        StructField("MDL", StringType()),
        StructField("OS", StringType()),
        StructField("OSVN", StringType()),
        StructField("AR", StringType())
    ])),
    StructField("MC", StringType()),
    StructField("FN", StringType()),
    StructField("NW", StructType([
        StructField("TP", StringType())
    ])),
    StructField("AL", StringType()),
    StructField("EN", StringType())
])
```

| value | EN |
| --- | --- |
| {"ID":"651551912131b2.07017577","SID":"169156360280217644","EP":1695895952305,"IP":"10.10.10.10","LN":"","VN":"2.4.0.0","DV":{"MK":"Jio","MDL":"JHSD200","OS":"JioOS 2","OSVN":"9","AR":"armeabi-v7a"},"MC":"02:00:00:00:00:00","FN":true,"NW":"TP":"wifi_5"},"AL":"GRIPdemo","EN":"Session_Start"} | Session_Start |

```
array_df = condition_df.withColumn("value_json",from_json(col("value"),when(condition_df.EN == "Session_Start", schema_session_start)))
```

I am getting below error when i am trying to convert :

ERROR:root:An error occurred: 'StructField' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

Comment: If the below answer solves your problem, use the checkmark next to the post to accept it

Comment: done, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of the `from_json` should be either string with schema or `StructType` (see [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_json.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json)), but in your case it's a `Column`.  If you want to apply a specific schema only to a given event type, then you need to do it differently - move `when` outside of `from_json`, something like this:

```py
array_df = condition_df.withColumn("value_json",
  when(condition_df.EN == "Session_Start",
     from_json(col("value"), schema_session_start)))
```